# Python make so if statment can only be satisfied a certain number of times

Tags: python

is there a way to make:

```
for i, line in enumerate(myfile.txt):
    if something in line:
        do something
```

this if statment only be satisfiable a specific number of times?

Comment: Introduce an another variable which you'd increment in each execution block. Then add an another condition to your existing if condition.

Comment: Keep a counter and increment it and `break` out of the loop or not run the `if` once it exceeds a certain number?

Comment: You can nest a simple counter inside your for loop. :)

Comment: maybe adding a counter so that after a certain number of times the if doesn't execute anymore?

Comment: Of course, there could be a lot of other, perhaps more pythonic approaches to this, e.g.: `for line in islice((l for l in myfile.txt if something in l), 42): do something`…

Comment: Yes, there probably is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information about what else might happen in the body of the loop, I would suggest simply keeping a separate counter of successful conditions. When that reaches a threshold, stop testing the condition.

```
matches = 0
for i, line in enumerate(myfile.txt):
    if matches < threshold and something in line:
        do something
        matches += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
counter = 0
for i, line in enumerate(myfile.txt):
    if something in line:
        counter += 1
    if counter >= some_number        
        do something
```

I have used `>=` sign. Use the relevant comparison you need.

Comment: I think a `<=` is more appropriate here. You want to **limit** the amount of executions, not **start after** a certain amount